# How can I convert a string to multiple lines?

Tags: python

**I'm trying to convert a long list of words into a multiple line .txt file**

Example:

```
longStringWithWords = 'THESE ARE WORDS THAT I LIKE'
```

into

```
THESE
ARE
WORDS
THAT
I
LIKE
```

I've tried this:

```
differentVar = longStringWithWords.split(' ')
file = open('filename.txt', 'a')
for i in differentVar:
   file.write(i)
   file.write('\n')
```

It's still not getting what I want.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: That should work.  What results are you getting?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please make a [mre] including the current output. You can [edit].

Comment: I get a blank file with this code if I don't close the file. Probably a buffering issues.

Comment: Are you running that code in a script or in an interactive session? They might behave differently where the file isn't explicitly closed. I ran it in a script and it worked fine.

Comment: Not sure about the OP, but I am...running in a notebook.

Comment: You should add file.close() as Will said, but your code ran fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the file:

```
file.close()
```

However, this is more efficient:

```
longStringWithWords = 'THESE ARE WORDS THAT I LIKE'
longStringWithWords = longStringWithWords.replace(' ', ' \n')
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(longStringWithWords)
```